# Filter to detect if Response::json was sent

Tags: laravel, filter, laravel-4, request, response

I have a filter. I want this filter to act **only if the page is displaying HTML and NOT if it's json or any other format**

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    if( $request->getMethod() == 'GET' && $request->getRequestFormat() == 'html' ) {
        // do something!
    }
});
```

In my Controller functions I return json data:

```
return Response::json($data);
```

However, `$request->getRequestFormat()` is still equal to 'html' and it shouldn't be.

I know that I can set the format to be 'json' like this:

```
Request::setRequestFormat('json');
return Response::json($data);
```

But it seems redundant. If I'm returning a `Response::json` it should know that it's json and not HTML. How can I detect that it's a `Response::json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `json` at all, it's `HTML` which contains some `string` inside a `div`. Remove the div and just pass the `json` using:

```
return Response::json($data);
```

Then in the client side, using `jQuery` parse the `json` data and create a div and append the data inside `div`, for example, in your `success callback` try something like this:

```
success(response) {
    // Parse the json if not parsed by jQuery
    var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
    if(obj.success) {
        $('<div/>', {id:"query-log"}).append(obj.data).appendTo('body');
    }
}
```

This may not accurate with your `json` data but hope you got the idea, in short, just pass the `json` data to the client side and manipulate it in the browser using `jQuery`.

**Update:** The better approach would be to provide the `dataType` when making the request using something like tgis:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function( data ) {

    }
});
```

Also you may use this:

```
$.getJSON( "url", function( data ) {
    // ...
});
```

So a request header will be sent to the server and you may check if the request is  expecting a `json` response using this:

```
if($request->wantsJson()) {
    //
}
```

This is the method in the request class:

```
/**
 * Determine if the current request is asking for JSON in return.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function wantsJson()
{
    $acceptable = $this->getAcceptableContentTypes();

    return isset($acceptable[0]) && $acceptable[0] == 'application/json';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was unclear. You are doing the opposite of what I want to do. I do NOT want the # of queries to be shown in JSON. Of course the `<div>` is HTML and not JSON. I want to detect if the response is Json so that I can then NOT show the # of queries

Comment: ignore the <div> stuff entirely, that was non essential. I updated the question

Comment: Thank you, `$request->wantsJSON()` and then setting the dataType in the jQuery seems like the cleanest solution to me.

Answer (score 5):

The requestFormat is something that isn't set automatically - you either provide it programattically via `setRequestFormat` or by including a POST/GET parameter `_format`.

If you want to check if a request is JSON you can do `$request->isJson()`, but it looks more to me like you're trying to check if the *response* is JSON? In which case you can do `$response instanceof Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse` or `$response->headers->get('Content-Type') == 'application/json'`

Answer (score 1):

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    if( $request->getMethod() == 'GET' && $request->getRequestFormat() == 'html' ) {

        // Test if response is JSON (PHP 5.3+ needed for this)
        json_decode($response);
        if ( json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE ) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You misunderstood me. Ignore the <div> stuff entirely, that was non essential. I updated the question

Comment: Updated answer. Just test if response is valid JSON or not. If it's not, assume it must be HTML.